# Requests library definition error when it has been imported

Tags: python, python-requests

Here is the problematic cell I have:

```
def loadSound(url):
    R = requests.get(url)
    rate, data = wavfile.read(BytesIO(R.content))
    data = data * 1.0 / (abs(data).max())
    if len(data.shape) > 1:  # for stereo data, use only first channel
        data = data[:,0]
    return data, rate

# the URLs of the wav files
urls = ["http://cd.textfiles.com/sbsw/INSTRMNT/TENORSA.WAV",
       "https://static.wixstatic.com/mp3/61e4ba_e696e98e0c5a466bb1537bdc3e0fc3b3.wav"]
sounds = []
for url in urls:
    sound, rate = loadSound(url)
    sounds.append((sound, rate))
```

I have imported `requests` before this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import animation
import scipy.signal as signal
import numpy as np

from IPython.display import Audio, display, HTML
from ipywidgets import interact

from scipy.io import wavfile
import requests
from io import BytesIO
```

and it is definetely installed, yet every time I try to run it, I get this error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-18ceaf2ddb63> in <module>
     12 sounds = []
     13 for url in urls:
---> 14     sound, rate = loadSound(url)
     15     sounds.append((sound, rate))

<ipython-input-4-18ceaf2ddb63> in loadSound(url)
      1 def loadSound(url):
----> 2     R = requests.get(url)
      3     rate, data = wavfile.read(BytesIO(R.content))
      4     data = data * 1.0 / (abs(data).max())
      5     if len(data.shape) > 1:  # for stereo data, use only first channel

NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

I have no idea how to solve this, given that the library is installed, imported and therefore defined... How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If it says `NameError: name 'requests' is not defined` you may be sure that `requests` doesn't exist, at any rate where you're running it.  Since you say *cell*, this is Jupyter?  Have you *run* the cell with 'import requests'?  Anyhow, add `import requests` directly above the code which uses it (in *that* cell) and run it there.

Comment: Do you have a file `requests.py` in the same folder?  What do you get if you do `import requests` and then `print(requests)`?  And for good measure `"get" in dir(requests)`